# Is there a library to share Oracle Connection Pools across multiple servers?

Tags: oracle, connection-pooling, scalability

Are there open-source solutions to share Oracle connection pools across server instances so application instances don't suck up limited connections? For example say I have a limit of 100 connections and 10 servers. I create 2 pools of 50, is there a way to share those pools of 50 across 5 servers?

Comment: Given that a connection is a handle to real physical resources on the server, you can't just move a connection from one server to another so it wouldn't make a lot of sense to me to try to share connections across servers.  You could use shared server connections in the database to increase the number of concurrent connections the database supports (though at a small potential performance cost) if the issue is that 100 connections isn't enough to support all the applications you need to run.

Comment: Depending on the clustering method used you may use Oracle's supplied load balancing (configuring RAC, connection managers and TNS, middleware pooling etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "5 servers" you mean 5 *application* servers, then you could look at using DRCP (Database Resident Connection Pooling) where the connection pool management is done via the database, and thus multiple app servers can all make use of a common connection pool.

Docs here https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/database-resident-connection-pooling.html#GUID-D4F9DBD7-7DC6-4233-B831-933809173E39